# Oven Insulation

Tags: microwave-oven

I have a stove that has been in storage, and it seems a mouse has gotten in and soiled the insulation pretty bad and needs to be replaced. My question is, What type of insulation do I need and where can I get it? I need to use the stove so I would like to be able to be able to go and pick the insulation up and not order it online.

Comment: Is this a microwave oven or a stove?